# Better way to parse

Tags: jquery, parsing, html

I want to parse this code to get the values

[image: Code to parse]

Currently I do

```
$(user).find('x item').each(function () {
    var first =  $(this).context.getElementsByTagName('value')[3].childNodes[0]['textContent'];
});
```

just to get "Sam" from Sam

I am sure there is a better and more reliable way do the same. I also want to find a way to avoid this kind of errors if any of the values are missing:

```
TypeError: $(...).context.getElementsByTagName(...)[2].childNodes[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting the exception I'm guessing the `$(user).find('x item')` selector is fine. So you can try

```
$(user).find('x item').each(function () {
      var first =  $(this).find('field[var="first"] value').text();
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff looking like had long day

Comment: can't you combine the `find` and remove `.each`?

Comment: @Vic not sure how many `item` elements are there... depends on the OP's structure it is not clear